# "(Class<T> clazz)" argument?

Tags: generics, jpa, persistence, dao

I don't know what to pass as (Class clazz) argument. I describe my project:

I have a GenericDAO.jave file within the following method:

```
public <T> T find(Class<T> clazz, Serializable id) {
    return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}
```

1. The class generated through JPA from the mysql table is named Idioma and has two attributes palabra and idioma.
2. In order to ask if "playa" is on my table, I need to use the above-mentioned method. to invoque this method from another file, I create the following variable to gain access to my GenericDao.java file :

   private GenericDao myDao;
3. Then, I also create the following method:

   ```
   public void findsAndReadsExistingIdiomaByPalabra() throws Exception {
       Idioma miIdioma;
       miIdioma=miDao.find(**clazz**, "playa")
   ```

   }

My doubt is:

I don't know what to write in **clazz**. Could anyone help me? If you need more information about my project, don't hesitate to ask.

thanks in advance

Comment: The magic that JPA does for you, is called Reflection and let's you (or JPA) inspect classes and objects at runtime. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clazz must be the class you will try to read. So if I understand your question right it must be `Idioma.class`

Comment: (Wild guess) I am in doubt that it must be the classname (java.lang.String). It should be rather the class object (java.lang.Class) that can be passed by your code snippet.

Comment: @Markus Idioma.class is the class object. The class name is Idioma.class.getName()

Comment: I agree. Shouldn't you better write class object instead of "Classname" in your answer?

Comment: @Markus Yes you are right. I have changed my answer.